# Group data using list KQL

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I am quite new using Kusto so I want to make list grouping differents network connections by the same source ip in differents ports. For example, i got a table like this:

| Source IP | Destination IP | Destination Port |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.1 | 10.0.0.1 | 80 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 10.0.0.2 | 8080 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 10.0.0.1 | 443 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 10.0.0.1 | 443 |
| 192.168.1.2 | 10.0.0.1 | 80 |
| 192.168.1.2 | 10.0.0.1 | 80 |

I need to show when this table gots more than 2 matches. This list will contain only unique registers, for example:

| Source IP | Destination IP | Destination Port |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.1 | 10.0.0.1 | 80 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 10.0.0.2 | 8080 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 10.0.0.1 | 443 |

So, I tried to use this query but it returns duplicated registers:

```
datatable(SrcIp:string, DstIP:string, DstPort:string)[         
'192.168.1.1', '10.0.0.1','80',
'192.168.1.1', '10.0.0.2','8080',
'192.168.1.1', '10.0.0.1','443',
'192.168.1.1', '10.0.0.1','443',
'192.168.1.2', '10.0.0.1','80',
'192.168.1.2', '10.0.0.1','80',]    | summarize
recurrence  = count(),
Details = make_list(pack("Source IP: ",SrcIp,"Destination Ip: ",DstIP,"Destination Port: ",DstPort))
by SrcIp| where recurrence >2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the input dataset unique in the first step, by adding a summarize over all columns (see also the [Kusto documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator#unique-combination)):

```
datatable(SrcIp:string, DstIP:string, DstPort:string)[         
'192.168.1.1', '10.0.0.1','80',
'192.168.1.1', '10.0.0.2','8080',
'192.168.1.1', '10.0.0.1','443',
'192.168.1.1', '10.0.0.1','443',
'192.168.1.2', '10.0.0.1','80',
'192.168.1.2', '10.0.0.1','80',] 
| summarize by SrcIp, DstIP, DstPort   
| summarize recurrence  = count(), Details = make_list(pack("Source IP: ",SrcIp,"Destination Ip: ",DstIP,"Destination Port: ",DstPort))
by SrcIp| where recurrence >2
```